# Why is os.mkdir() returning error when it shouldn't (beginner question)?

Tags: python

Okay so this probably isn't the most beautiful piece of code (I'm still learning) but I was hoping to create a folder using os.mkdir() the first time the program was run.

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error
`FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'Assets'`

So I designed a little function which creates a text file. If the text file reads `true` then nothing happens. Else, it will create a text file and write `true` to it. Then, the next time the program is run os.mkdir() will not run and there will be no error.

I still keep getting the error even though hypothetically it should read `true` from the file and `pass` instead of trying to run os.mkdir()

Again, this probably isn't the best way to do this, but I was hoping to get some answers as to why I keep getting this error.

Thank you.

```
import os

def init_files():
    #creates the initial files for the game to run properly

    init_file = open('init_file_check.txt', 'w+')
    init_file_check = str(init_file.read())
    init_file.close()

    #checks to see if os.mkdir() needs to be run or if already run

    if init_file_check == 'true':
        pass
    else:
        os.mkdir('Assets')
        
        init_file = open('init_file_check.txt', 'w+')
        init_file.write('true')
        init_file.close()
init_files()
```

Comment: Why are you opening a file in `w+` mode if you want to read the existing contents?

Comment: And why are you using a separate file to track whether a directory exists, instead of just checking whether the directory exists?

Comment: So that I can create the file `init_file_check.txt.` when it doesn't already exist. Opening in `r` mode wouldn't allow me to create it afaik.

Comment: Don't check if the directory exists; that creates a race condition where it can be created between your check and your attempt to create it. Just call `os.mkdir`, and catch any `FileExistsError` that it might raise.

Comment: You can debug this. Simple debugging should tell you that `init_file_check` doesn't contain what you think it contains. That should cause you to check how you're reading the text file and then how you're opening the text file, to determine which you've done incorrectly. Then you can check the [open docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and you'll see that `Modes 'w+' and 'w+b' open and truncate the file.`

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I can definitely just check whether the directory exists to condense the code, but regardless the error message still remains

Comment: @jarmod hmm when I try to `print(init_file_check)` it is saying that it isn't defined, even though I defined it as equal to `str(init_file.read())`. Any ideas?

Comment: `w+` truncates the file; `init_file_check` will be an empty string because you essentially erased the old contents of the file before you read from it. (`w+` is for when you want to be able to read from the file *after* you have written to it, without having to close the file and reopen it in read mode.)

Comment: At the very least, you can just use `os.path.exists` to see if your directory already exists, rather than using another file to record the fact that you created it. But don't do that, because it still leaves your code vulnerable to a race condition.

Comment: @chepner ah makes sense, so from the moment the file is opened in `w+` mode it will erase all contents. I thought it would only overwrite it when write() was used. Regardless, I'm going to use `try` and `except` instead

Comment: You could use `a+` to avoid truncating the file, but 1) you would have to explicitly use `seek` to move the file pointer from the end of the file to the start to read the contents and 2) you have no intention of doing any kind of writing, so all you really need is `'r'` (which is the default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do any checks. If you need the directory, create it. If it already exists, `os.mkdir` will raise an exception that you can catch and ignore.

```
def init_files():
    try:
        os.mkdir('Assets')
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
```

The end result of this function is that `Assets` will exist, whether or not it previously did. (Ignoring that fact that someone might delete it after you create it, but there's nothing sensible you can do about that.)

---

Doing otherwise exposes you to a race condition. You can check if the directory does not exist however you like, but it's always possible someone else could create the directory before your code executes `os.mkdir`, in which case you have to be prepared to catch the exception anyway.

Comment: Thank you, will look more into `try` and `except`. This seemed to work!

Comment: Also I will read more about race conditions, thank you.

Comment: EAFP is more applicable when dealing with "pure" code. Here, the bigger problem is that you can't trust the result of your permission check to remain valid before acting on it. It's not just easier, it's *correct*.

Comment: "Ignoring that fact that someone might delete it after you create it, but there's nothing sensible you can do about that." - unfortunately, there's no "create-and-open directory" system call that would give you a file descriptor for the directory to close this race condition. (A directory file descriptor can be used with calls like `openat` to open files relative to the directory, even if the directory gets unlinked or moved around.)

Comment: Since the delete-after-creation race condition is unavoidable, closing the other race condition doesn't really gain all that much. It's still a good habit, but it doesn't really protect you here.

Comment: Yeah, whether or not the directory *continues* to exist is really an entirely separate topic. The code here just protects your script from uncaught exceptions resulting from the creation process itself.

Answer (score 1):

This error would occur when you have a file or a directory already existing with that name. Here's a little example with outputs to demonstrate(I've started with an empty directory):

```py
>>> open('test', 'w').close()
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir('test')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'test'

>>> open('test.txt', 'w').close()
>>> os.remove('test')
>>> os.mkdir('test')
>>> os.mkdir('test')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'test'
```

At first I create the file 'test' and then to make a directory of that name, but to no avail. After deleting the file and creating a file named 'test.txt' I can successfully make a directory named 'test'.
However, now I cannot create another directory of that name.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. It's hard to read, and people cannot copy&paste it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will edit the answer with code instead!

Answer (score 1):

So here is the detail why your code is not working:

- You have used `w+` which erases the contents inside the `txt` file everytime this line is executed:

```
init_file = open('init_file_check.txt', 'w+') #overrides its previous content
```

For the first time you have executed the program, you will not face any problem but the problem will arise when you rerun the program for the 2nd time because the above line of code will override your txt file which contained `true` word and your txt file will be empty which results in `init_file.read()` to be empty everytime it is being executed.
So `else` condition will execute everytime when you run the program because that `w+` erases everything in your file.

Solution:

```py
import os

def init_files():
    #creates the initial files for the game to run properly

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join('init_file_check.txt')):
        pass
    else:
        try:
            os.mkdir('Assests')
            init_file = open('init_file_check.txt', 'w+')
            init_file.write('true')
            init_file.close()
        except:
            pass
            
init_files()
```